# Always show a value highst when sorting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I Oracle, I have a table with following values

```
1
2
4
10
```

I always want 2 to show up highest following by all other values in DESCending order, as follows :

```
2
10
4
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `order by` a value you build with a `case`; for example:

```
with tab(col) as (
    select  1 from dual union all
    select  2 from dual union all
    select  4 from dual union all
    select 10 from dual 
)    
select col
from tab
order by case when col = 2 then 1 else 2 end asc,
      col desc
```

gives:

```
       COL
----------
         2
        10
         4
         1
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below if column is not null

```
with tab(col) as (
    select  1 from dual union all
    select  2 from dual union all
    select  4 from dual union all
    select 10 from dual 
)    
select col
from tab
ORDER BY NULLIF(col, 2) desc NULLS FIRST
```

output

```
COL
2
10
4
1
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd4efab325a1a0476a5c848e07fdeb7b)